# Is there any good way of SELF-updating running web application?

Tags: asp.net

as stated - it needs to be a "self-update" similar like Wordpress... I haven't thought through because of my knowledge limits... (I haven't found any good answer from the web yet /asp.net c#)

anyone can give some help/ perhaps some code example would be better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the code, But i can tell you the general concept behind that.

Keep a public API/ Webservice which returns the latest version number of the site/ app.
In your website/ app, add a method which makes a call to this service to get the latest version number. compare it with what you have in your local application. If the one you received from the service is different than the one you have, That means there is a new version available. Then show a link to download the latest version.